# The specified resource name contains invalid characters Error generating SAS url for blob even though blob name is valid

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create an Sas Url for a blob through a web api
but i keep getting this error.
I've used [this blog post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-sas-token-for-azure-blob-storage-using-managed-identity/) as a reference but changed some things i don't need.
(I've tried doing exactly as the post says, copy pasted, still doesn't work)

this is my code:

```
var container = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("Files");
var client = container.GetBlobClient("dev-test/test-json.txt");
// I've tried to use just the name of the blob without the file extension and that doesn't work either

if (!client.CanGenerateSasUri)
   return string.Empty;

var builder = new BlobSasBuilder
     {
         BlobContainerName = container.Name,
         BlobName = client.Name,
         Resource = "b",
         StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
         ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
         Protocol = SasProtocol.Https
     };

builder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

Uri sasUri = client.GenerateSasUri(builder);
string url = sasUri.ToString();
return await Task.FromResult(url);
```

i get a url that seems to be fine according to examples I've seen but when i try to access that url i get the error mentioned in the title.

when i use Generate SAS inside the azure container itself, it's working fine.
but through my code it doesn't.

this is the token i get from the azure blob when i click Generate SAS:

```
sp=r&st=2022-06-12T21:00:00Z&se=2022-06-13T21:00:00Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=2RhYyiWMGQxzidNQgsVFaiNJRDhRCKmHkQRnHM3x7J8%3D
```

this is the token i get through the api request:

```
sv=2021-06-08&spr=https&st=2022-06-13T11%3A13%3A56Z&se=2022-06-14T11%3A13%3A56Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=1Ttgdeti6NC8vcINmCNBQL7ejdE0ajNHhJRGAdGNANg%3D
```

Comment: What’s the name of your container and blob?

Comment: container name is Files and the blob is in dev-test folder and the file name is test-json

Comment: Ok, through your question i realized what the problem was. the container name should be lower case as well.
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Container name should be lowercase as well

```
var container = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("files");
```